# Speeding up Boussinesq equations solving?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I am working on Boussinesq equation. The notebook can run perfectly for only 0.6 steps and then the calculation starts running slowly after 0.7. All boundary conditions seemed fine. I am unsure if I used the correct method to solve this problem.

```
   tmax = 10;
Monitor[
 AbsoluteTiming[
  {xVel, yVel, pressure, temperature} = NDSolveValue[
     Flatten@{op == {0, 0, 0, 
         Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], convectiveLeft] + 
          Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], convectiveRight] + 
          Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], convectiveTop]}, bcsflow, 
       bcstemperatures, ic}, {u, v, p, T}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t,
       0, tmax},
     Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA", 
         "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 2, 
         "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", 
           "LinearSolveMethod" -> "Pardiso"}},
       "PDEDiscretization" -> {
         "MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {
           "FiniteElement",
           "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}
         }
       },
     EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])
     ];
  ],
 currentTime
 ]
```

These are my error msg.

NDSolveValue::fembcib: The finite element mesh has internal boundaries. Boundary conditions with 'True' as a predicate will set boundary conditions at these internal boundaries. It is recommended to use a less general predicate than 'True' for the boundary conditions {DirichletCondition[p==0,True]} in this case.

NDSolveValue::indexss: The DAE solver failed at t = 0.`. The solver is intended for index 1 DAE systems and structural analysis indicates that the DAE is structurally singular.
[Code here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w07fbsoro8od3hi/Empty%20box-question.nb?dl=0)

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2535261).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi yes, it's the same person. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I do not. When you crosspost the same question on multiple sites it is good etiquette to add crosslinks. That way the people trying to help you can check if the question has already been answered elsewhere and if so they do not have to waste time answering it.

Comment: @LionSahara Please, check, that the Rayleigh number in your problem is about 2.22412*10^10, and therefore this is turbulent convection. Also mesh you used is very rough for this problem. Even for laminar convection with $Ra=10^5$ I have used option `"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001`  to compare with other solvers - see my post on https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064?p_p_auth=KT89yn6t

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you for your suggestion. I changed Ra value and Maxcellmeasure as you suggested. The simulation time took forever. The simulation has been running for an hour and t is roughly 0.26 steps. I have no idea what is the problem here.

Comment: @LionSahara It is not clear what problem do you try to solve.  Can you explain what region and boundary condition in your problem?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I left it running until it crashed. The error msg is NDSolveValue::ndsz: At t == 0.265566436483142`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

To answer your question, I am trying to simulate an empty box in which \[CapitalOmega]2 and \[CapitalOmega]3 are PCM. We can neglect the phase transition at this stage. Simply say it's cavity free convection with 2 sources of heat. Tatm is 40c, Tpcm is -40c, Tair inside the box is -40c as well.

Comment: @LionSahara I have two stable code for your problem with Ra up to 10^6 on your `mesh` and on $\Omega$ as well. I don't understand what are you writing about the phase transition.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Please ignore the phase change for this stage. can you share the code please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use scaling as in our model on this [page](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064?p_p_auth=KT89yn6t).See also Vahl Davis, G.de (1983) : Natural convection of air in a square cavity : A bench mark numerical solution. Int. J. Numer. Methods Fluids 3, 249-264.
A system of equations describing free convection can be written in nondimensional form as follows
$\nabla .\vec u=0, \frac{d\vec u}{dt}=Pr\nabla ^2\vec u -RaPrT\frac {\vec g}{g}$

$\frac {dT}{dt}=\nabla^2T$

$ d/dt =\partial/\partial t +(\vec u .\nabla )$

$\vec u$ is velocity field vector, $T$ - temperature, $\vec g $ - gravity vector, $Pr$ - the Prandtl number, $Ra$ - the Rayleigh number.

Note, that the temperature scale 40-(-40)=80 is included in `Ra` definition. Code  should be modified as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][];
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
ClearAll[length, height, offsetx1, offsetx2, offsety];
sizes = {length -> 21/10, height -> 15/10,
   offsetx1 -> 1/10, offsetx2 -> 1/10,
   offsety1 -> 1/10, offsety2 -> 2/10
   };

Geometry
\[CapitalOmega]1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, height}] /. sizes;
\[CapitalOmega]2 = 
  Rectangle[{0, 0} + {0.2, 1.5 - 0.049}, {0.69, 0.049} + {0.2, 
     1.5 - 0.049}];

\[CapitalOmega]D1 = 
  RegionDifference[\[CapitalOmega]1, \[CapitalOmega]2];
\[CapitalOmega]3 = 
  Rectangle[{0, 0} + {1.2, 1.5 - 0.049}, {0.69, 0.049} + {1.2, 
     1.5 - 0.049}];
\[CapitalOmega]D2 = 
  RegionDifference[\[CapitalOmega]D1, \[CapitalOmega]3];
Mesh

\[CapitalOmega] = 
  DiscretizeRegion[\[CapitalOmega]D2, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5];
meshes = ToBoundaryMesh /@ {\[CapitalOmega]1, \[CapitalOmega]2, \
\[CapitalOmega]3};
bmesh = FEMUtils`BoundaryElementMeshJoin @@ meshes;
boxCoordinate = {1.05, 0.8};
PCMCoordinate1 = {0.5, 1.46};
PCMCoordinate2 = {1.5, 1.46};
markerColors = {Blue, Orange, Green};
markerCoordinate = {{boxCoordinate}, {PCMCoordinate1}, \
{PCMCoordinate2}};
markerspec = MapIndexed[{First@#1, First@#2} &, markerCoordinate];

mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionMarker" -> markerspec, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 5*10^-3];
mesh["Wireframe"[]]
mesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> 
   Map[Directive[FaceForm[#], EdgeForm[]] &, markerColors]]]

Show[{bmesh["Wireframe"], 
  Graphics[MapThread[{PointSize[0.02], #1, 
      Point /@ #2} &, {markerColors, markerCoordinate}]]}]
Material Properties
region = <|"air" -> 1, "pcm" -> 2|>;
vars = {T[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};
HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, <|"MassDensity" -> \[Rho], 
  "SpecificHeatCapacity" -> Cp, "ThermalConductivity" -> k|>]
airpara = {Subscript[\[Rho], air] -> 
    QuantityMagnitude[ThermodynamicData["Air", "Density"]], 
        Subscript[Cp, air] -> 
    QuantityMagnitude[
     ThermodynamicData["Air", "IsobaricHeatCapacity"]],
        Subscript[k, air] -> 
    QuantityMagnitude[
     ThermodynamicData["Air", "ThermalConductivity"]]};
HS30Npara = {Subscript[Cp, pcmS] -> 2.1, Subscript[Cp, pcmL] -> 2.7, 
        Subscript[k, pcmS] -> 2.34, Subscript[k, pcmL] -> 0.6,
        Subscript[\[Rho], pcmS] -> 1430, latent -> 200, 
        tpmin -> -34, tpmax -> -26 };
PUFpara = {\[Rho] -> 50, cp -> 1500, k -> 0.025};

pars = <||>;
pars["MassDensity"] = 
  If[ElementMarker == region["air"], Subscript[\[Rho], air], 
   Subscript[\[Rho], pcmS]];
pars["SpecificHeatCapacity"] = 
  If[ElementMarker == region["air"], Subscript[k, air], Subscript[k, 
   pcmS] ];
pars["ThermalConductivity"] = 
  If[ElementMarker == region["air"], Subscript[k, air], 
   Subscript[k, pcmS]*IdentityMatrix[2]];
op = HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars]

Initial and Boundary Condition
Tpcm = 0;
Tair = 0;
ic = {u[0, x, y] == 0,
   v[0, x, y] == 0,
   p[0, x, y] == 0,
   T[0, x, y] == 
    Piecewise[{{Tpcm, ElementMarker == region["pcm"]}, {Tair, 
       ElementMarker == region["air"]}}]};

Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], convectiveLeft] = 
  HeatTransferValue[
   x == 0 , {T[t, x, y], t, {x, y}}, <||>, <|
    "HeatTransferCoefficient" -> 0.7, "AmbientTemperature" -> 1|>];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], convectiveRight] = 
  HeatTransferValue[
   x == length /. sizes, {T[t, x, y], t, {x, y}}, <||>, <|
    "HeatTransferCoefficient" -> 0.7, "AmbientTemperature" -> 1|>];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], convectiveTop] = 
  HeatTransferValue[
   y == height /. sizes, {T[t, x, y], t, {x, y}}, <||>, <|
    "HeatTransferCoefficient" -> 0.7, "AmbientTemperature" -> 1|>];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], convectiveBottom] == 
  HeatTransferValue[
   y == 0 /. sizes, {T[t, x, y], t, {x, y}}, <||>, <|
    "HeatTransferCoefficient" -> 0.7, "AmbientTemperature" -> 1|>];
bcstemperatures = {
  DirichletCondition[
    T[t, x, y] == 
     0, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]2 || {x, 
       y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]3];
  }

ClearAll[\[Nu], \[Epsilon], Pr, Ra];
g = 9.8;
\[Alpha] = 0.0034;
\[Nu] = 1.48*10^-5;
\[Beta] = 2.17*10^-5;
L = (4*2.1*1.5)/(2*(2.1 + 1.5));
Temp = 40;
Subscript[T, \[Infinity]] = 0;
Ra -> ((g*\[Alpha])/(\[Nu]*\[Beta]))*(Temp - 
     Subscript[T, \[Infinity]])*L^3;
parameters = {Pr -> 0.7, Ra -> 10^6};

op = {
    
    
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, y]
     + Inactive[Div][(-Pr Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}]
     + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]} . Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}]
     + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(p\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, y], 
        
    
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, y]
     + Inactive[Div][(-Pr Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}]
     + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]} . Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}]
     + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(p\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, y] - Ra Pr T[t, x, y],
        
    
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, y] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, y],
        
    
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(T\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, y]
     + Inactive[Div][(-Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}]
     + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]} . Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}]
    
    } /. parameters;
walls = {
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]
   };
reference = DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0];
bcsflow = {walls, reference };
```

Solution over `mesh` with $Ra=10^6$ takes about 120 s

```
tmax = 1;
Monitor[
 AbsoluteTiming[
  {xVel, yVel, pressure, temperature} = NDSolveValue[
     Flatten@{op == {0, 0, 0, 
         Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], convectiveLeft] + 
          Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], convectiveRight] + 
          Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], convectiveTop]}, bcsflow, 
       bcstemperatures, ic}, {u, v, p, T}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t,
       0, tmax},
     Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA", 
         "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 2},
       "PDEDiscretization" -> {
         "MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {
           "FiniteElement",
           "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}
         }
       },
     EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])
     ];
  ],
 currentTime
 ]
```

Visualization

```
{StreamDensityPlot[
  {xVel[tmax, x, y], yVel[tmax, x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] 
   xVel["ElementMesh"],
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All,
  StreamPoints -> Fine, PlotLegends -> Automatic
  ], DensityPlot[
  temperature[tmax, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] 
   temperature["ElementMesh"],
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All,
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic
  ]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Solution on $\Omega$ with $Ra=10^5$ takes about 90 s
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thank you very much. I get my code works perfectly. Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I have a question. I understand that the temperature scale 40-(-40)=80. Why do we have to set up the initial temperature of PCM at 0 and Tatm is 1? What if I want to use Tpcm at -25 and Tatm at 30. Do I need to calculate a new Ra?

Comment: Yes, any temperature scale should be included in Ra definition, since  force depends on temperature scale included in Ra.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the equation like a crystal.

Comment: Yes, convection model in this form is very suitable for computation with Mathematica FEM up to transition to turbulence.

Comment: This is clear. It works perfectly with this form. I'm still curious why the model does not work with the Navier stokes form. I mean this form https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Multiphysics/ModelCollection/BuoyancyDrivenFlow.html 
I will find more info. Thank you very much.

Comment: The Navier-Stokes form you cited is the model of stationary convection while you try to solve nonstationary convection.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. Thank you again

Comment: Hi Alex, I am sorry to disturb you again. I am revisiting the code. Unfortunately, I copied the code above and I got the following error.
NDSolveValue: Equation or list of equations expected instead of Null in the first \
argument 
and Set: Lists {xVel,yVel, pressure,temperature} and 

... I realize that I fixed it before and it worked very well. Now I forgot how to fix it. Hope you can help.

Comment: @LionSahara It looks like code here has been corrupted. It could be better to send you file with working code.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you mind sharing the code through dropbox or Google Drive?

Comment: Could you please sharing the code? I would love to see what the problem is. Thank you very much.

Comment: @LionSahara  I dropped it on  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3113902 . Please take it and maybe add comment.